# Find the $\delta$ to establish that $f(x,y) = |x|^{y}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

The question originally asked to determine if the function can be extended to be continuous at $(0,0)$. I did that by doing the following:

Letting $y = x$:

$$f(x) = |x|^{x} = e^{x\log{|x|}} \\ \rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0} e^{x\log{|x|}} = 0$$

So after establishing this I need to find a $\delta$ to prove continuity. I don't have any constructive ideas on how to rewrite my expression:

$$|f(x,y) - f(0,0)| = |f(x,y)| = \bigg| |x|^{y} \bigg| < \epsilon $$

The one thing that came to mind was:

$$e^{y\log{|x|}} < e^{y\log{\delta}} < \epsilon $$

After a little mor manipulation I arrive at letting $\delta$:

$$\delta = e^{\frac{\log{\epsilon}}{y}}$$.

Since I originally let $y = x$, should I do the same here or by keeping it as $y$ it implies that whatever choice of $y$ I make it would not affect the result?

Feedback?

Answer (score 1):

The limit at $(0,0)$ does not exist.

$f(x,0)=1$ if you approach the origin from the x-axis

$f(0,y)=0$ if you approach the origin form the y-axis

So you cannot extend it continuisly at $(0,0)$

Comment: I had posted previously about this question and it seems I was trying to convince myself that one of these three questions could be extended at $(0,0)$, but apparently none of them can. So now I'm trying to understand why my prof would ask such a question to us?